# Are saves from Burnout Paradise: The Ultimate Box compatible with Burnout Paradise Remastered?

Tags: pc, burnout-paradise

I own [Burnout Paradise: The Ultimate Box](https://store.steampowered.com/app/24740/Burnout_Paradise_The_Ultimate_Box/) on Steam. If I purchase [Burnout Paradise Remastered](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1238080/Burnout_Paradise_Remastered/), will I be able to import my old save file from The Ultimate Box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not officially. There also aren't any fanmade converters.

**However**, [according to this reddit comment by u/burninrubber0](https://www.reddit.com/r/Burnout/comments/9ttxrf/comment/e98ag0k/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), you could edit a OG Paradise save into being compatible with the Remaster (the commenter however warns that "doing so is time-consuming and requires pretty intimate knowledge of the save", while also linking to a Google Sheets document featuring info about the structures of both OG and Remaster savefiles).